# No implicit reference conversion error between generic interface concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am using Unity to resolve a generic interface to a concrete type that implements that interface:

```
_container.RegisterType<IItemLocatorFactory<Job, ILocatorViewModel<Job>>,
            ItemLocatorFactory<Job, BaseJobViewModel>>();
```

The declaration of `IItemLocatorFactory<Job, ILocatorViewModel<Job>>` is:

```
public interface IItemLocatorFactory<TData, TModel> 
    where TData : IMyEntity
    where TModel : ILocatorViewModel<TData>
```

The class `ItemLocatorFactory<Job, BaseJobViewModel>` implements the interface `IItemLocatorFactory<Job, ILocatorViewModel<Job>`:

```
public class ItemLocatorFactory<T, TModel> : IItemLocatorFactory<T, TModel>
    where T : IMyEntity
    where TModel : ILocatorViewModel<T>
```

The class `BaseJobViewModel` is declared like this:

```
public class BaseJobViewModel : ILocatorViewModel<Job>
```

But this gives me compile error complaining that there is no implicit reference conversion:

> Error  1   The type 'UI.ItemLocator.Infrastructure.DefaultItemLocatorFactory.ItemLocatorFactory' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UI.ItemLocator.Infrastructure.DefaultItemLocatorFactory.ItemLocatorFactory' to 'Interfaces.UI.ItemLocator.IItemLocatorFactory>'.

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a different `TModel` in the interface and the implementation.

This is the same reason `List<Derived>` isn't castable to `IList<Base>` although `List<T>` is castable to `IList<T>` and `Derived` is castable to `Base`.

If you want `ItemLocatorFactory<T, TModel>` to be assignable to `IItemLocatorFactory<T, TBaseModel>` you need to make the interface's `TBaseModel` *covariant* by declaring it with `out`:

```
public interface IItemLocatorFactory<T, out TModel> 
{
  /* use TModel here in a covariant way */
}
```